# How to cancel UITapGestureRecognizer?

Tags: iphone, ios, touch, uitapgesturerecognizer

I noticed that the single tap happens when the touch dragging is performed quickly.

I want to cancel the single tap if the user moves the touch.

How can I do this?

Comment: Do you want the drag to be recognized, or do you just not want the tap to be recognized if the user drags a little by accident (are you implementing a pan or swipe as well as a tap)?

Answer (score 1):

> I noticed that the single tap happens when the touch dragging is performed quickly.

My suggestion is to do nothing. Assuming you have everything set up properly then what you are going to end up doing is creating an app specific behavior for dragging simply to accommodate your personal preference. This could confuse your customers and possibly prevent your app from getting approved.

If the problem you are experience cannot be duplicated in other apps then I would guess that you are doing something incorrectly with respect to the responder chain, and you should focus on fixing that first.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume that you don't want to cancel the tap gesture itself (once the tap gesture has fired, I don't think you can cancel the gesture, it's already done!), but rather the code fired from it.

What you could do is create a timer, and delay the action created by the tap gesture by a second or two.  You then have that time interval to cancel the action.